# Magento 2.2 - Custom options are not saved programmatically on cart update

Tags: magento2, cart, custom-options, programmatically

Initially, while adding an item to cart the custom options and other details are saved successfully to cart. When reupdating the cart with updated custom options are not saved in cart programmatically.

Comment: Check this link for reference for to update cart items https://github.com/prathap2406/Magento2-ItemComment/tree/master/Rage/ProductComment

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran thank you, let me review and get back on this.

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran At first, the products are cart and all the respective Magento custom values are updated in quote_item_option table. On updating the cart values, the table quote_item_option is not updated with the latest values. FYI, we are using Magento's custom option.

Comment: The concept of that extension is as same as you they've added custom column and you're custom option column that's all. Anyway post your code above

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-to-change-item-custom-option-in-cart/td-p/100781

we use the same code which is on the above link.